# 0x0000000000000000 in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-address

I have a view, and I want to remove it in a particular situation.

```
if (self.superview) {

    [self removeFromSuperview]; // breakpoint point here
}
```

I `lldb` it :

```
(lldb) po self.superview
0x0000000000000000
```

How to judge the `superview` equals to `0x0000000000000000`?

Comment: This means it is allocated & is not nul

Comment: @iYoung How to juedge the superview equals to 0x0000000000000000？

Comment: Please post some more code to see what `self` is.

Comment: "How to judge the superview equals to 0x0000000000000000" That's what `if (self.superview)` is already doing. What problem are you having?

Comment: If you want to remove any subview from super view first check is super view contain that sub view. Along with this check is anything nil. According to your code self must be super view. If self is not super view you are doing wrong
Please provide more details related to self. And also check above points also. Your info is incomplete please update your question,

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to send `removeFromSuperview` to a view even if the view isn't in a superview. If the view isn't in a superview, the message will have no effect. So testing `self.superview` is not necessary.

When `self.superview` prints as `0x0000000000000000`, that means it is `nil`, which means `self` is not in a superview.